# Slash or Backslash where using a mulitple platform programs

Tags: c#, windows, web, path, operating-system

I'm building a service that deals with images on windows and has a web part.
I know that windows uses backslash to separate hirerachies and everyone else uses
slash. in order of my image to show on the web part I had to use slash for my relative (to project folder) image path (or am I?), and when I wanted to delete a photo using a web click I had to give the system a full path so I got this "mixed path":

C:\Users\source\repos\ImageService\ImageServiceWeb\to/2017/10/20171001_150622.jpg

where the directory ImageServiceWeb is my project directory.
To my suprise when I used this command on Visual Studio 2017:
System.IO.File.Delete(photo.FullPath);
it actually deleted the image and not raised an exception.
How and why does it happen?
Thanks!

Comment: windows when convert win32 path to nt path replace / to \. as result we can use / in path

Comment: *Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the "\\?\" prefix as detailed in the following sections.* - from [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)